# Listar dados para os Option

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Estou tentando listar dados do banco para os meus options, mas não sei como fazer isso eu tentei da seguinte seguinte forma ai em baixo, eu quero que quando o formulário for enviado eu quero enviar o `ID` daquele local, mas no select quero que mostre a `descrição` daquele `id`.

```
//criei a query = $consulta
  $consulta = "SELECT denuncia.id, data, imagem ,denuncia.descricao, b.descricao as bloco_descricao, doq.descricao as oque_descricao, id_bloco, id_denuncia_oque, qual_descricao, u.matricula, nome, sobrenome FROM denuncia INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.id = denuncia.id_usuario INNER JOIN bloco b ON b.id = denuncia.id_bloco INNER JOIN denuncia_oque doq ON doq.id = denuncia.id_denuncia_oque";
   //prepara a query
   $con = $connection->prepare($consulta);
   //executar o comando sql
   $denuncia = $con->execute();
   //juntar todos os resultados do select em um vetor de arrays
   $denuncia = $con->fetchAll();
```

Aqui está meus Options

```
<select select="required" class="form-control" name="id_denuncia_oque" id="sel1" required="required" >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Ex: Laboratório</option>
    <?php  foreach ( $denuncia as $den   )  {  ?>                    
        <option value="<?$den["id_denuncia_oque"]; ?>"> 
            <?php echo $den["oque_descricao"]; ?>
        </option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Você esta usando algum framework ou é php puro?

Comment: Seria conveniente [edit] a pergunta descrevendo melhor seu problema (qual resultado você esperava, e qual foi o resultado que saiu em vez disso). Aproveite para colocar o do HTML gerado pelo PHP.

Comment: Bom o que eu queria fazer era lista os dados do banco para esses Options, tenho um tabela chamado denuncia _oque, que os campos dela são id e descricao. O que eu queria fazer era lista a descricao dessa tabela para meu Options, mas quando o meu formulário fosse enviado eu não queria enviar a descricao mas sim o id da descricao.

Comment: Esse Select ai do banco era da minha outra pagina, e tem muito campos que não precisarei usar nessa pagina.

Comment: Do jeito que está ai não funciona porque? Tipo, tem o `id_denuncia_oque ` no value do option, certo?

Comment: Acabei me esquecendo mas esse id_denuncia_oque é onde vai ser armazenado os dados do id da tabela denuncia_oque

Comment: Ocorreu algum erro no php? Qual foi o resultado no HTML sua página?